# Javascript only firing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, name-attribute

long-time lurker here asking my first public questions because I am truly stuck.

I'm working on a hosted shopping cart platform so I only have access to add code in certain designated divs. I have a javascript code that I'm calling externally (because inline is bad unless you have to, right?)

So my issue is, There is a `<select>` dropdown that I do NOT have direct access to change HTML and the silly shopping cart platform didn't give it an id, only the name attribute is set.

I need to clear the `<div id="result_div">` when the `<select name="ShippingSpeedChoice">` drop-down is clicked so I have:

`$("[name=ShippingSpeedChoice]").change(function(e) {
            $("#result_div").empty();
        });`

It fires once, but that's it. My question is, how do I make it fire EVERY TIME the `<select name="ShippingSpeedChoice">`  is clicked?

Here's all the relevant javascript (in case it's preventing `#result_div` from clearing somewhere):

```
    $("[name=ShippingSpeedChoice]").change(function(e) {
        $("#result_div").empty();
    });

    $("#btn_calc").click(function(e) {      /// onclick on Calculate Delivery Date button
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You want it to fire every time they click on it, even if they don't change the value? Bind it to the `click` event instead of the `change` event.

Comment: You should work on reducing the code in your question to a bare minimum. Plus you left out the HTML part.

Comment: can you also check whether the select element is recreated between the first and the second clicks.... if so have a look at event delegation

Comment: I'm not sure that would be the proper specification for a shopping cart, it wouldn't make much sense to update the screen if nothing has changed for the selection. Although he did use the wording "change everytime it is clicked" I do believe he might have meant something else.

Comment: Also - I think you mean [5] here? ;)     `FXONtransitdays[4] = "Friday";
    FXONtransitdays[4] = "Saturday";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still wasn't able to use the `name` attribute to call the function, so I found a way around it by using the `id` of the `td` the `ShippingSpeedChoice` dropdown was in:

```
    $("#DisplayShippingSpeedChoicesTD").change(function(e) {
        $("#result_div").empty();
```

And it fires every time now. Thank you so much for all your feedback & assistance  - I still wish I could figure out how to use the `name` attribute rather than the `id`, but that will be a puzzle for another day!

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to happen every time the element is clicked, use `.click()` rather than `.change()`. The latter only fires if they select a different value from the menu than it had before.

```
$("[name=ShippingSpeedChoice]").click(function(e) { $("#result_div").empty(); });
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, I've tried both `.click` and `.change` - honestly whether it fires on `.click` or `.change` I don't care, the point is that it only fires once, and it needs to fire EVERY time there is a change OR a click on <select name="ShippingSpeedChoice">. any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle but there is so much external content (from the hosted shopping cart) that it didn't replicate reality. I ended up using the `id` of the parent element anyway. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd probably try and setup the shopping cart select to have an id.

```
$("[name=ShippingSpeedChoice]").id = 'shopping_cart_select';
```

then try binding the "change" function to the element via it's id.

```
$('#shopping_cart_select').bind('change', function(){
//rest of code goes here
}
```